# how to extract index of first alphabetic character of line in awk

Tags: awk

How can one extract the index of the first alphabetic character of line in awk?

I was hoping that

```
echo 123XYZ | awk '{print index($1,"[:alpha:]")}'
```

would return 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) says a regexp is not allowed inside `index()`:

> index(in, find)
>
> [...]
>
> With BWK awk and gawk, it is a fatal error to use a regexp constant for
> find. Other implementations allow it, simply treating the
> regexp constant as an expression meaning ‘$0 ~ /regexp/’. (d.c.)

---

You could use `match()`:

```bsh
echo "123XYZ" | awk '{match($0,/[[:alpha:]]/); print RSTART}' 
4
```

This will match the first leftmost alphabetic character. After a `match()`, built-in variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` contain the index and the length of the matched string, so we print the first one.

---

Note: This: `[:alpha:]` is a class of characters, does not define by its own a regexp to match. To make it mean "one alphabetic character", we have to enclose it into `[]`, like this: `[[:alpha:]]`.

From `man awk`:

> A character class is only valid in a regular expression inside the brackets  of  a  character  list. Character  classes  consist  of  [:,  a  keyword  denoting the class, and :]